# How can I constantly update a few text fields in a JavaFX GUI?

Tags: java, javafx

What is the best way to keep few text fields constantly updating in background thread? I'm logging some variables from quadrotor fly which I'm keeping in DronCoordinator class. Every time they change(100ms) I want to update their values in GUI text fields.  I've tried with updateMessage() method from Task class, but in that way I can only keep updating 1 textfield. I need to add 3 or 4 more variables to keep updating. It works good but only with 1 variable to update.

```
public class ApplicationControler implements Initializable {


@FXML
private Canvas artHorizon;

@FXML
public TextField pitchValue;

@FXML
private TextField rollValue;

@FXML
private TextField yawValue;

@FXML
private TextField thrustValue;

@FXML
private Button start;



private Service<Void> backgroundThread;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}

@FXML
private void applicationStart(ActionEvent event) {

    backgroundThread = new Service<Void>() {


        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {

            return new Task<Void>() {


                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {


        //This is the place where class which uptades variables starts

                        updateMessage(DronCoordinator.pitch);


                    return null;
                }

            };

        }
    };

    backgroundThread.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {

            pitchValue.textProperty().unbind();


        }
    });



    pitchValue.textProperty().bind(backgroundThread.messageProperty());

    backgroundThread.restart();

}

}
```

Comment: If this works as intended for the `pitchValue` textfield, whats wrong with doing it the same way for the other 3? Also, please be more specific about what you are wanting to happen.

Comment: Do you want to make interaction with the GUI while simultaneously running the task in the background ? if this is what you want you have to use Platform.run later

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I can't make that, becouse backgroundThread.messageProperty() it's just one string, so when I bind the same messageProperty() with 4 text fields, all fields will show the same value.

Comment: @RahulSingh I'm logging some variables from Quadrotor fly every 100ms, and I'm keeping them in DronCoordinator class. I want also to update them in textFields in the same way, but I don't need to make interaction with the GUI.

Comment: if you are updating text fields you are interacting with the gui isn't it

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry, I didn't quite understand that. So there isn't any other option but use Platfor.run later ?

Comment: This is what i can think. There can be other ways but if you are updating gui elements you have to use the runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model object that you can pass from your task to the updateMessage. The idea behind this is to collect the various values in one object and then update the GUI with all values instead of update each value separately. The model can look similar to this:

```
public class DroneModel {
  private double pitch;
  private double roll;
  private double yaw;
  private double thrust;

  public double getPitch() {
    return pitch;
  }

  public void setPitch(double pitch) {
    this.pitch = pitch;
  }

  public double getRoll() {
    return roll;
  }

  public void setRoll(double roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
  }

  public double getYaw() {
    return yaw;
  }

  public void setYaw(double yaw) {
    this.yaw = yaw;
  }

  public double getThrust() {
    return thrust;
  }

  public void setThrust(double thrust) {
    this.thrust = thrust;
  }
}
```

Then your update method looks like this:

```
public void updateMessage(DroneModel model) {
  pitchValue.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPitch()));
  rollValue.setText(String.valueOf(model.getRoll()));
  yawValue.setText(String.valueOf(model.getYaw()));
  thrustValue.setText(String.valueOf(model.getThrust()));
}
```

The essential part is how you call this update method, you have to use runLater, as mentioned by @RahulSingh:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> updateMessage(droneModel));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method to your textbox in javafx :

```
textbox.rawText() ->  which keeps on updating your textbox whatever is currently in it.
```